# Como posso mudar o valor do input após uma condição?

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho seguinte script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    var modaliddade;
    var produto = 43;
    var idproduto;
    var plano = "PLANO";

        //Usuarios
        $(function () {
            $("#codigouser").autocomplete({
                source: "usuarios.php",
                minLength: 2,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $('#codigouser').val(ui.item.codigo);
                    $('#nome').val(ui.item.nome);
                    $('#cpf').val(ui.item.cpf);
                    $('#idusuario').val(ui.item.idusuario);
                    $('#modalidade').val(ui.item.modalidade);
                      modalidade = ui.item.modalidade; 
                    $('#cota').val(ui.item.cota);
                    $('#modalidadeassociado').val(ui.item.modalidadeassociado);
                }
            });
        });
        //+ produtos
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var max_fields = 32;
            var wrapper = $(".produto"); //Fields wrapper
            var add_button = $(".add-camera"); //Add button ID

            var x = 0; //initlal text box count
            $(add_button).click(function (e) { //on add input button click
                e.preventDefault();
                if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
                    x++; //text box increment
                    $(wrapper).append('<div class="form-group">\
                            <input type="text" name="idproduto' + x + '" class="form-control produtoCounter" id="idproduto' + x + '"  Size="1" placeholder="Id" readonly />\
                            <input type="text" name="ean' + x + '" class="form-control produtoCounter" id="codigo' + x + '"  Size="10" placeholder="Código" readonly />\
                            <input type="text" name="nome' + x + '" class="form-control produtoCounter" id="nome' + x + '"  Size="50" placeholder="Nome" required />\
                            <input type="text" name="referencia' + x + '" class="form-control produtoCounter" id="referencia' + x + '"  Size="10" placeholder="Referencia" readonly />\
                            <input type="text" name="quantidade' + x + '" id="quantidade' + x + '"  class="form-control produtoCounter quantidade" Size="2" placeholder="Quant." onchange="somarTotais()" required />\
                            <input type="text" name="valorunitario' + x + '" id="valorunitario' + x + '" onkeydown="FormataMoeda(this,10,event)" onkeypress="return maskKeyPress(event)" class="form-control produtoCounter valorunitario" Size="5" placeholder="Valor" readonly />\
                            <input type="text" name="desconto' + x + '" id="desconto' + x + '" value="0" class="form-control produtoCounter desconto" Size="2" onchange="somarTotais()" placeholder="Desc" />\
                            <input type="text" name="desconto1' + x + '" id="desconto1' + x + '" class="form-control produtoCounter desconto1" Size="2" onchange="somarTotais()" style="display: none;" />\
                            <a href="#" class="remove-camera">Remover</a>\
                            </div>');


                    $("#nome" + x).autocomplete({
                        source: "produtos.php",
                        minLength: 2,
                        select: function (event, ui) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            $('#idproduto' + x).val(ui.item.idproduto);
                             idproduto = ui.item.idproduto;
                            $('#nome' + x).val(ui.item.nome);
                            $('#codigo' + x).val(ui.item.codigo);
                            $('#referencia' + x).val(ui.item.referencia);
                            $('#valorunitario' + x).val(ui.item.valorunitario);
                            //$('#desconto' + x).val(ui.item.desconto);
                            $('#desconto1' + x).val(ui.item.desconto);


                        }
                    });

                }
            });

            $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove-camera", function (e) { //user click on remove text
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent('div').remove();
                somarTotais();

                x--; //text box decrement

                $(".produtoCounter").each(function (elm) {
                    var count = elm + 1
                    $(this).attr("name", "ean" + count);
                    $(this).attr("value", "ean" + count);
                    x = elm + 1;
                });
            })
        });

</script>
if ((modalidade == plano) && (produto == idproduto)) {
    //muda valor do input
}
```

Preciso mudar este valor :

```
<input type="text" name="desconto' + x + '" id="desconto' + x + '" value="0" class="form-control produtoCounter desconto" Size="2" onchange="somarTotais()" placeholder="Desc" />\
```

Quando uma condição for verdadeira.
Se for o value passa de 0 para 30.
Tem como fazer isso?

Comment: Resposta é sim, tem como. Agora você precisa nos dizer onde você quer colocar a condição, seria melhor explicar o que realmente quer fazer para obter um resultado melhor.

Comment: Qual é a condição exatamente?

Comment: Eu acabei de editar o código, coloquei a condição.peço desculpas acabei subindo o código antigo.

Comment: @FernandoTrilha procure sempre simplificar sua pergunta, colar toda sua lógica (ou boa parte dela) não vai te ajudar a econtrar a resposta. Entenda seu problema e coloque o trecho de codigo que apenas representa sua dúvida, assim você vai conseguir ajuda muito mais rápido. Além disso tavez você criar um contexto imaginário fora do seu problema real pode ser uma otima escolha também

Comment: Entendi, irei fazer isso nas próximas vezes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você que criar o input já com o valor resolvido da condição você pode fazer isso direto no atributo `value` do elemento basta resolver essa condição em uma variável e concatená-la no value do input semelhando você fez com x;

```js
/**
 * Variavel resolvida com a condição desejada
 */
var inputValue = ((modalidade == plano) && (produto == idproduto)) ? 30 : 0;

<input type="text" name="desconto' + x + '" id="desconto' + x + '" value="'+ inputValue +'" class="form-control produtoCounter desconto" Size="2" onchange="somarTotais()" placeholder="Desc" />
```

Veja o trecho do seu código alterado seguir:

```js
$(add_button).click(function (e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment
        /**
         * Variavel resolvida com a condição desejada
         */
        var inputValue = ((modalidade == plano) && (produto == idproduto)) ? 30 : 0;

        $(wrapper).append('<div class="form-group">\
            <input type="text" name="idproduto' + x + '" class="form-control produtoCounter" id="idproduto' + x + '"  Size="1" placeholder="Id" readonly />\
            <input type="text" name="ean' + x + '" class="form-control produtoCounter" id="codigo' + x + '"  Size="10" placeholder="Código" readonly />\
            <input type="text" name="nome' + x + '" class="form-control produtoCounter" id="nome' + x + '"  Size="50" placeholder="Nome" required />\
            <input type="text" name="referencia' + x + '" class="form-control produtoCounter" id="referencia' + x + '"  Size="10" placeholder="Referencia" readonly />\
            <input type="text" name="quantidade' + x + '" id="quantidade' + x + '"  class="form-control produtoCounter quantidade" Size="2" placeholder="Quant." onchange="somarTotais()" required />\
            <input type="text" name="valorunitario' + x + '" id="valorunitario' + x + '" onkeydown="FormataMoeda(this,10,event)" onkeypress="return maskKeyPress(event)" class="form-control produtoCounter valorunitario" Size="5" placeholder="Valor" readonly />\
            <input type="text" name="desconto' + x + '" id="desconto' + x + '" value="'+ inputValue +'" class="form-control produtoCounter desconto" Size="2" onchange="somarTotais()" placeholder="Desc" />\
            <input type="text" name="desconto1' + x + '" id="desconto1' + x + '" class="form-control produtoCounter desconto1" Size="2" onchange="somarTotais()" style="display: none;" />\
            <a href="#" class="remove-camera">Remover</a>\
            </div>');


        $("#nome" + x).autocomplete({
            source: "produtos.php",
            minLength: 2,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('#idproduto' + x).val(ui.item.idproduto);
                 idproduto = ui.item.idproduto;
                $('#nome' + x).val(ui.item.nome);
                $('#codigo' + x).val(ui.item.codigo);
                $('#referencia' + x).val(ui.item.referencia);
                $('#valorunitario' + x).val(ui.item.valorunitario);
                //$('#desconto' + x).val(ui.item.desconto);
                $('#desconto1' + x).val(ui.item.desconto);


            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Ola Vinicius, obrigado pela ajuda.fiz uns ajustes e deu certo, muito obrigado pela ajuda amigo.